# Structuremap V4.4.2 Create EntityFramework DbContext Per Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, structuremap, structuremap4

I have an **ASP.Net MVC application** with Entity Framework. I have used **Structuremap V4.4 as IoC Container tool**.

I want to make an instance of DbContext in each request.

**My configuration is as follows:**

```
var unique = new UniquePerRequestLifecycle();

For<ContextDB>().LifecycleIs(unique)
     .Use<ContextDB>().Transient();
```

**And I use it like this everywhere:**

```
public UserRepository(ContextDB context) : base(context)
{
}
```

But, `when I profile the project with EFProfiler, it is not One DbContext`!!

What is the problem here?

What should I do?

Comment: since you have used `UniquePerRequestLifecycle`, it is supposed to have one unique instance of `ContextDB` per request. **Limited to my level of understanding..!

Comment: How to create another ContextDB? Exactly my problem.